# Can't connect to Internet after update

Tags: 16.04

I had an Install updates yesterday. I have ran it and after it finishes it asks me to restart cause it says that in order to finish the update, the system must be restarted. After a few minutes I did that. But after doing so, I can no longer connect to the Internet. Both through lan cable or wifi. I am not sure what to do. Can someone advice what to do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking on the Network settings (while pinging google from a terminal, at the same time) if I disable the network and put it back up again, the ping stops and goes on again, which is fine. But, if I open another terminal and ping there google, it won't which is weird.

I looked again in the Network settings and saw IPv6 being turned on. I am not entirely sure if this was turned on before, but I tried to turn it off. After doing that, everything seems to work fine again. I guess that must be it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Have you checked that you have ticked *Enable Networking*? If not, go check it.

Comment: Thanks for coming back, and yeah it is enabled. I've been enabling/disabling it as part of my debugging above. Wasn't able to describe it above, but that was it. But anyway, it's all good now :)